# How do I order by _entry type_ when looping through entries in a template?

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

I currently have multiple sections like so:

```
{% for craft.entries.section('mySection').type('oneType')... %}
   ... {% endfor %}
{% for craft.entries.section('mySection').type('anotherType')... %}
   ... {% endfor %}
```

But I would rather have a single loop like this:

```
{% for craft.entries.section('mySection').order('type, title')... %}
```

However, the `type` referred to in `order()` will in the DB query refer to `craft_elements.type` which in this case always will be `Entry`.

Is it possible to order by *entry type*?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Craft's [`group`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter for this, but you'll lose the ability to
use the `paginate` tag to paginate your entries by doing so.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').order('title') %}
{% set entriesByType = entries|group('type') %}

{% for type, entriesInType in entriesByType %}
    <h3>{{ type }}</h3>

    {% for entry in entriesInType %}
        <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Craft doesn't join the entrytypes table when you query for entries. You could order by `typeId`, but that's probably not what you want.

Fortunatelly there's an `elements.buildElementsQuery` event, that allows to modify element queries.

```
craft()->on('elements.buildElementsQuery', function(Event $event) {
    $query = $event->params['query'];

    if (strpos($query->order, 'entrytypes') !== false) {
        $query->join('entrytypes entrytypes', 'entrytypes.id = entries.typeId');
    }
});
```

Add this code to the `init()` method of your [business logic](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) plugin and you can now order by your entry type handles.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'mySection',
    order: 'entrytypes.handle desc, title asc',
}) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use my [Preparse Field plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft), which let's you run twig code when an entry is saved, and saves the result of the twig as plain text in the field.

If you just wanted to sort alphabetically by entry type name, you could put something like this in your preparse field settings:

```
{{ entry.type | lower }}
```

And then go:

```
{% for craft.entries.section('mySection').order('myPreparseField, title')... %}
```

Or, you could do more advanced logic if you want some custom order, like:

```
{{ entry.type=='type1' ? 1 : (entry.type=='type2' ? 2 : 3) }}
```

Make sure you get rid of whitespace in the output, either by not adding any to your code (like above), or by using `{{ spaceless }}` or `-` on tags.